# Combine selectors only when both emited values

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

I have 2 selectors selectAllJournals, selectAllAccounts that emit values at different times.

The combined selector needs a value from  selectAllAccounts  as soon as there is a value emitted from selectAllJournals. Right now I check in the mapping function mapJournalListViewModel if the selectAllAccounts  emitted values. But that feels awkward. One problem I see is that mapJournalListViewModel will be callled twice: once for an emitted value from selectAllJournals and  selectAllAccounts. Is there a better way, so that mapJournalListViewModel only gets called when both selectors emitted values?

```
export const selectJournalListViewModel = createSelector(
  selectAllJournals,
  selectAllAccounts,
  (journals, accounts) =>
    journals.map((j) => mapJournalListViewModel(j, accounts))
);



function mapJournalListViewModel(
  journal: Journal,
  accounts: Account[]
): JournalListViewModel {
  return {
    id: journal.id,
    date: journal.date,
    debitAccountName: accounts?.find(
      (a) => a.id === journal.transactions[0].account.id
    )?.name!,  // <--- accounts checked for null because the selector might emit values only later
   
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional logic:

```
export const selectJournalListViewModel = createSelector(
  selectAllJournals,
  selectAllAccounts,
  (journals, accounts) =>
    (journals && accounts) ? journals.map((j) => mapJournalListViewModel(j, accounts)) : []
);
```